# Why do we have mutableOrderedSetValueForKey yet not OrderedSetValueForKey?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

What about if we just want to look at what's there rather wanting to change stuff and then we want to access it by it's key rather than using dot notation?

For example:

I have object called `CatalogData`

I can do `CatalogData.Images` to get the pages.

However, say I have a function that return `NSManagedObject` and I want to pass `@"Images"` to that function.

So, eventually it'll get something like

```
[anNSManagedObjectThatisactuallyaCatalogData orderdSetforKey:@"Images"]
```

Well, we can't have that.

So why?

Should we use the good old `objectForKey`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use

```
[anNSManagedObjectThatisactuallyaCatalogData valueForKey:@"Images"]
```

which returns an `NSOrderedSet` if "Images" is an ordered to-many relationship.

Comment: Why valueForKey? Why not objectForKey?

Comment: Actually I forget. Yea, why not?

Comment: @JimThio: `objectForKey` is only for `NSDictionary`. A managed object is not a dictionary, but it is "Key-Value compliant", so you can use `valueForKey`.